# Use macro annotation to reduce boilerplate

Tags: scala, macros, annotations, scala-3

I would like to (if it is even possible) use annotations (and probably macros) to reduce boilerplate in classes declaration (I have lots of classes with very similar declarations).

I want to reduce

```
class Foo(using bar: Bar[Foo]) extends Baz:
    //content that uses 'bar'
```

to

```
@MyAnnotation
class Foo:
    //content that uses 'bar' ?
```

I know that Scala has two annotation classes `StaticAnnotation` and `MacroAnnotation` but I can't really figure out the difference has I have seen examples using `StaticAnnotation` with macros as well...

**Questions:**

- Is it possible and does it makes sense ?
- If so, can you provide an example of macro annotation used in a similar manner (to reduce boilerplate) ?
- What's the difference between `StaticAnnotation` and `MacroAnnotation` ?

Comment: 1. I could be possible. 2. It doesn't make sense, as it make your code harder to read without much gain: for anyone reading it it will be a surprise that `Foo` extends `Baz`, there is some `bar` available, default constructor doesn't work - type declaration basically lies and you cannot put a cursor and jump to definition in your IDE because they are not there. Macro annotations were abused in Scala 2 and only a few of their use cases passed the test of time - I'd say good examples were implicits (Scala 3 has `derives` build-in) and `@newtype. Everything else was just obfuscation.

Comment: This macro would save literally _1 short line_.

Comment: It would actually save half of a line, and add a full additional line instead... At least in this small example.

Comment: I did something like this in an older Scala 2 project, with methods, i.e. `@myAnnotation def foo: Bar` became `def foo(implicit thing: Thing): Bar`. It was pretty convenient to type, but ultimately I regretted it because no IDE understood it; actions like auto-filling method stubs where the annotation was part of the method would not carry over the annotation, and if I ever had to directly reference `thing` in the body of the method, the IDE would think it was an error. I wish I had defined it as `def foo: ThingAction[Bar]` with some monad-ish ThingAction type instead.